# Why is python unable to read all headers from each TIFF image in a given folder?

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I was playing around with the following code snippet and it seems to be working, but when I checked the output, it shows that after the first image full header is read, the next one is just partially read and proceeds to the next one (which is third image) but the third image full header is correctly read.

This is the code that I'm using, and I'm not sure which part have problem with it...
At first, I thought that the image header was corrupt, but after checking the its header, everything seems to be fine and having same format as others.

```
import os
from PIL import Image, ExifTags

# specify the directory path where the images are stored
directory = "path_to_image_folder"

# loop through all the files in the directory
for filename in os.listdir(directory):
    if filename.endswith(".tiff"):
        # construct the full file path
        filepath = os.path.join(directory, filename)

        try:
            # open the image
            with Image.open(filepath) as image:
                # extract the EXIF metadata
                exifdata = image.getexif()

                if exifdata:
                    # loop through all the tags present in exifdata
                    for tag_id, value in exifdata.items():
                        tagname = ExifTags.TAGS.get(tag_id, tag_id)
                        print(f"{filename} - {tagname}: {value}")
                else:
                    print(f"{filename} - No EXIF metadata found.")
        except Exception as e:
            print(f"{filename} - Error: {e}")
```

Console output of the code:

```
# The results I get is this and a bit unusual...
# For nearly half of the file that program read, it show this output as below...
top_785_3567_87_87_0.tiff - StripOffsets: (648, 8796, 16944, 25092, 33240)
top_785_3567_87_87_0.tiff - SampleFormat: 3
top_785_3567_87_87_0.tiff - SamplesPerPixel: 1
top_785_3567_87_87_0.tiff - RowsPerStrip: 21
top_785_3567_87_87_0.tiff - StripByteCounts: (8148, 8148, 8148, 8148, 5044)
top_785_3567_87_87_0.tiff - XResolution: 1.0
top_785_3567_87_87_0.tiff - YResolution: 1.0

# Suppose should be read the whole file like the below...
top_785_3815_87_87_0.tiff - ImageWidth: 97
top_785_3815_87_87_0.tiff - ImageLength: 97
top_785_3815_87_87_0.tiff - BitsPerSample: 32
top_785_3815_87_87_0.tiff - Compression: 1
top_785_3815_87_87_0.tiff - PhotometricInterpretation: 1
top_785_3815_87_87_0.tiff - ResolutionUnit: 1
top_785_3815_87_87_0.tiff - ImageDescription: date="2023-02-27"
voltageInKiloVolt="130.0"
integrationLevel="2"
recipe="E7200-64540-RevC-UpdateNew"
filterCap="None"
resolution=23000
projectionProcessing="no_processing"
cameraGain="1"
postProcessing="no_processing"
machineID="3148"
binningMode="BackwardCompatible"
systemType="S2EX"
refDes="Cu_60.0_Solder_1.6"
currentInMicroAmp="250.0"
reconstruction="Average"
stageSpeed=[1.0]
zHeightInNanos=3735200
```

I used [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oskgK.png) and [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D3kS0.png) as sample files.

Comment: This seems to read the headers on some of my local tiff files. What's your output?

Comment: Hi, I have upload the sample output in the hyperlink up there, please click on it and have a look

Comment: I wouldn't normally download something from a third party, but I pulled test2.tiff and the output looks correct. I think your output was truncated and was not the actual output from this code. There is an extra newline in the content of ImageDescription, and it's like you just stopped because there was a blank line. Terminal issue?

Comment: try not printing the value when tag_id == 0x10e, or just join its value into one line?